# Installing Pango 1.40.3

Tags: linux, gtk3, fontconfig

Recently I've installed `GTK+ 3.22` and one of its dependencies was `Pango 1.40`.
After installing `Pango 1.40` I've noticed that when I build a game I made with `Cocos2d-x` I get the following error: `In file: /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 undefined reference to 'pango_matrix_get_font_scale_factors'`.

I've asked `how to fix this error` on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330461/undefined-reference-in-libpangoft2), and someone told me to run `nm /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0`. The output is very long, but I've noticed that the function that I am looking for is really undefined `U pango_matrix_get_font_scale_factors`.

I looked for `how to install Pango 1.40` and it was required that I install `HarfBuzz-1.3.2`, `FreeType-2.7` and `Fontconfig-2.12.1`. If I install the 3 aforementioned dependencies and then reinstall `Pango 1.40`, any application that uses GTK+ will not start, including the login screen and all other desktop environments would crash. Therefore I had to go into recovery mode and uninstall those libraries in order to be able to start a DE.

I am using Debian 8 and my question is, how do I install `Pango 1.40`, with all its dependencies, without breaking my system?